# How to improve SQL query performance for HAVING (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

These 2 queriess are taking several minutes on tables of several millions rows (2 tables: `torrents` and `dates`). None of the columns are indexed I believe. I don't know SQL well. Is there any way to make them faster?

Here are the queries:

```
// torrents with no dates yet (116278ms)
  SELECT
    torrents.*
  FROM
    torrents
  LEFT JOIN 
    dates ON dates.infohash = torrents.infohash
  GROUP BY
      torrents.infohash
  HAVING 
     COUNT(dates.date) = 0

// yesterday high stats torrents (348024ms)
  SELECT
    torrents.*
  FROM
    torrents
  LEFT JOIN 
    dates ON dates.infohash = torrents.infohash
  GROUP BY
    dates.dateInfohash
  HAVING
    dates.date = '2019-09-10'
  ORDER BY 
    peers DESC
  LIMIT 5000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clauses

```sql
// torrents with no dates yet
      SELECT torrents.*
      FROM torrents
       LEFT JOIN dates ON dates.infohash = torrents.infohash
       WHERE dates.date IS NULL

// yesterday high stats torrents
      SELECT torrents.*
     FROM torrents
     LEFT JOIN dates ON dates.infohash = torrents.infohash
     WHERE dates.date = '2019-09-10'
     ORDER BY peers DESC
     LIMIT 5000
```

The first one probably doesn't even need the `WHERE dates.date IS NULL` since I assume that there's no record in the `dates` table without a date. **UPDATE:** But then you would need to change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I think the WHERE clause on `dates.date IS NULL` for the first query is important. "Bring me every record from table `torrents` where there is no date" would be solved with this type of query. Otherwise I think you are right on. I can't even imagine either query runs without error, but perhaps sqlite allows non-full-group-bys...

Comment: @JNevill I updated my answer to recommend changing the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` in the case where a `dates.date` record doesn't exist. But I agree, I don't use sqlite, but I'm surprised that it would allow the original syntax.

Comment: is WHERE faster than HAVING?

Comment: Yes, `WHERE` is faster than `HAVING`. But beyond that, the `GROUP BY` is only needed with some type of aggregate selection, like `SUM()` or `COUNT()`, which are not necessary here. `HAVING` is done after the rows are selected, while `WHERE` limits the number of rows selected. So in this case, where you have several million rows, you are selecting them all then filtering out the ones that don't match your `HAVING`, while `WHERE` will only retrieve the rows that meet the requirements. I hope this explanation makes sense.

Comment: It does thanks. What about creating an index on dates.date or dates. infohash or dates.peers, would that help?

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as "accepted". In the meantime, the indexes will help where you are referencing columns in your queries, but they also add overhead when creating records, so you have to balance the performance based on how many records are created vs how often you query them. Also, primary keys are automatically indexed, so you don't need to create them yourself in the column is the primary key for the table.

Comment: thanks it did solve it. what made the biggest different was the indexes combined with the WHERE

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM torrents t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dates d
                  WHERE d.infohash = t.infohash
                 );
```

For this, you want an index on `dates(infohash)`.

And for the second query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM torrents t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dates d
              WHERE d.infohash = t.infohash AND
                    d.date = '2019-09-10'
             )
ORDER BY t.peers DESC
LIMIT 5000;
```

For this, use the index `dates(infohash, date)` -- this can replace the simpler index for the first query.  You can also try an index on `torrents(peers desc, infohash)`, although I'm not certain that will eliminate the sorting.